# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project grpcDemo1: Compilation failure

Tags: grpc-java

how to solve this compilation error when running the pom.xml file as maven build?
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project grpcDemo1: Compilation failure

how to solve this compilation error when running the pom.xml file as maven build?

```
Building GrpcDemo1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ grpcDemo1 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- protoc-jar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1:run (default) @ grpcDemo1 ---
[INFO] Protoc version: 3.6.0
protoc-jar: protoc version: 3.6.0, detected platform: windows-x86_64 (windows 10/amd64)
protoc-jar: embedded: bin/3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-windows-x86_64.exe
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar6409895902087218719\bin\protoc.exe, --version]
libprotoc 3.6.0
[INFO] Protoc command: C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar6409895902087218719\bin\protoc.exe
[INFO] Additional include types: C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3262709963962878932\include
[INFO]     google/protobuf/any.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/api.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/duration.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/empty.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/source_context.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/struct.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/type.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
[INFO] Input directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\resources
[INFO] Include directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3262709963962878932\include
[INFO] Output targets:
[INFO]     java: C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO]     grpc-java: C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO] Resolving artifact: io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0, platform: windows-x86_64
[INFO]     Processing (java): user.proto
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar6409895902087218719\bin\protoc.exe, -IC:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3262709963962878932\include, -IC:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\resources, --java_out=C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\java, C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\resources\user.proto]
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO]     Processing (grpc-java): user.proto
[INFO]     Plugin path: C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protoc-gen-grpc-java10752485391677429324.exe
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar6409895902087218719\bin\protoc.exe, -IC:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar3262709963962878932\include, -IC:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\resources, --grpc-java_out=C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\java, --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protoc-gen-grpc-java10752485391677429324.exe, C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\resources\user.proto]
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- protoc-jar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1:run (default) @ grpcDemo1 ---
[INFO] Protoc version: 3.6.0
protoc-jar: protoc version: 3.6.0, detected platform: windows-x86_64 (windows 10/amd64)
protoc-jar: embedded: bin/3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-windows-x86_64.exe
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar11467980593706459900\bin\protoc.exe, --version]
libprotoc 3.6.0
[INFO] Protoc command: C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar11467980593706459900\bin\protoc.exe
[INFO] Additional include types: C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar4481037934572117071\include
[INFO]     google/protobuf/any.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/api.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/duration.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/empty.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/source_context.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/struct.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/type.proto
[INFO]     google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
[INFO] Input directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\resources
[INFO] Include directories:
[INFO]     C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar4481037934572117071\include
[INFO] Output targets:
[INFO]     java: C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO]     grpc-java: C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\java (add: main, clean: false, plugin: null, outputOptions: null)
[INFO] Resolving artifact: io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0, platform: windows-x86_64
[INFO]     Processing (java): user.proto
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar11467980593706459900\bin\protoc.exe, -IC:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar4481037934572117071\include, -IC:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\resources, --java_out=C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\java, C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\resources\user.proto]
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO]     Processing (grpc-java): user.proto
[INFO]     Plugin path: C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protoc-gen-grpc-java8301737362570634034.exe
protoc-jar: executing: [C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar11467980593706459900\bin\protoc.exe, -IC:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protocjar4481037934572117071\include, -IC:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\resources, --grpc-java_out=C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\java, --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=C:\Users\Anshika\AppData\Local\Temp\protoc-gen-grpc-java8301737362570634034.exe, C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\src\main\resources\user.proto]
[INFO] Adding generated classes to classpath
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ grpcDemo1 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ grpcDemo1 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Anshika\Desktop\internships\jio\internship2023\grpc\grpcDemo1\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Anshika/Desktop/internships/jio/internship2023/grpc/grpcDemo1/src/main/java/com/yrrhelp/grpc/userGrpc.java:[20,18] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.227 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-23T15:58:25+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project grpcDemo1: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Anshika/Desktop/internships/jio/internship2023/grpc/grpcDemo1/src/main/java/com/yrrhelp/grpc/userGrpc.java:[20,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Generated
[ERROR]   location: package javax.annotation
```

here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.yrrhelp</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpcDemo1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>GrpcDemo1</name>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

        <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean generate-sources compile install</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <!-- compile proto file into java files. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
                <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <includeMavenTypes>direct</includeMavenTypes>
                            
                            <inputDirectories>
                                <include>src/main/resources</include>
                            </inputDirectories>
                            
                            <outputTargets>
                                <outputTarget>
                                    <type>java</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                                </outputTarget>
                                <outputTarget>
                                    <type>grpc-java</type>
                                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0</pluginArtifact>
                                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                                </outputTarget>
                            </outputTargets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  
</project>
```

how to successfully run the pom.xml file without any compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [grpc-java documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java#download), it instructs you to include the dependency:

```xml
<dependency> <!-- necessary for Java 9+ -->
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.53</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

That provides the Generated class that was removed in Java 9.

Note that Protobuf 3.6 and gRPC Java 1.15 are from 2018. You should upgrade them.